TSX: a variable set to either a Map<string,string> get() result or '' is shown as "string | undefined"
TSX question. I define an ES6 Map which is Map<string,string>, where all of the following constants are strings. There are no issues here.
export const CALLER_TYPE_TITLE_MAP = new Map<string,string>([
    [CALLER_TYPE_ID_1, CALLER_REF_TITLE_1],
    [CALLER_TYPE_ID_2, CALLER_REF_TITLE_2],
    [CALLER_TYPE_ID_3, CALLER_REF_TITLE_3],
    [CALLER_TYPE_ID_4, CALLER_REF_TITLE_4]
]);

Then I define a variable which is either a result from a get() from this Map, or an '' empty string:
export const validateCallerRefFirstName = (val:string, callerRefCallerType:string) => {
    let title = CALLER_TYPE_TITLE_MAP.get(callerRefCallerType) ?
                CALLER_TYPE_TITLE_MAP.get(callerRefCallerType) : '';

The variable title as shown as let title: string | undefined in VS code after this declaration. There is no way for it to have this type, because undefined cannot occur. Neither the function param callerRefCallerType is defined as string|undefined nor the keys/value in the  CALLER_TYPE_TITLE_MAP.
If no result exists in the Map, title will never get the undefined value, it will go to ''.
So what's happening here?
Because of this issue, I can't use the variable title in common string functions like str.replace(substr, title) that require a string-only param. The only syntax that works is to do
let title = CALLER_TYPE_TITLE_MAP.get(callerRefCallerType);
str.replace(substr, title ? title : '');


Can anyone help with this? The question is, Why does TSX flag {map.get('key') ? map.get('key') : ''} as string|undefined when in fact it's never undefined?
